# Compressing files with zip freezes desktop

Tags: zip

When I try to compress files using the zip `zip -r foo.zip foo` on the desktop. It hides some files and folders, I cannot move the icons (but they can be opened). Relogging solves the problem. Has anyone encountered this problem before? I have no such problem with tar.

Im running 20.04.3 LTS version on asus*x550jx*, size of file is 20kB.

Comment: I used to have this problem on a 386 SX/25 running Windows 3.1 back in the early 90s. That said, I don't think you're running Win3.1 on a 386. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) the size of the files you're compressing (2) some hardware information (3) any other *actionable* information that might offer some hints? With this, it *might* be possible to offer a solution 

Comment: are you trying to zip files in the ~Desktop folder ? I suggest you copy them to a temporary directory and zip the there

Comment: @GiorgosSaridakis Yes, I'm aware of that. Just curious if this is a global problem. I will try to recreate this in vm.

Comment: the ~Desktop is a regularly updated system folder, you should not mess with it a lot. If you want to compress files located inside it, zip the destination file to another directory. Yes, it is a global issue, not really a problem

Comment: Read `man zip` an add the `--verbose` option to see what's going on.